# The opposite of this jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been using a bit of jquery in my asp.net project and are trying to select all unchecked checkboxes that match a certain style class - and this 1st bit works fine.

```
$('span.cbmac input:not(:checked)').each(function() {";
//etc
});
```

I would like to use the opposite of this query, ie select all checked boxes that match the span tag cb.mac.

I've tried

```
!$('span.cbmac input:is(:checked)').each(function() {";
//etc
});
```

and a few variations but no luck so far, any ideas appreciated.

Comment: ! is javascript notation for `if set, give me false, if not, give me true`. jQuery, as a library, cannot change the meaning of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any selector is an implied `:is()`. You would use `span.cbmac :input:checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$('span.cbmac input:checked)').each(function() {;
//etc
});
```